# How to multiply two 23-bit numbers using 16-bit memory locations

Tags: binary, hardware, multiplication

How can you multiply two unsigned 23-bit numbers if you only have memory locations that are 16-bits?

I am not performing these operations using x86 instructions, so information related to x86 will be ignored.

Comment: Hi starbox! You'll need to clarify your question: remove irrelevant tags (what has this to do with Matlab?), add more information (how are the numbers encoded, etc)

Comment: @jpjacobs the numbers are unsigned (which i stated).  You need two words to store each number so the numbers are incoded like this: 000000000XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (thus you have two 16-bit words to hold 1 23-bit number.  Every number is unsigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean you can only multiply two 16-bit numbers at a time.

First I'm going to say that `a` and `b` are the numbers we want to multiply. They are between 17 and 32 bits in size (which covers your 23). However big they are they're zero padded out to an unsigned 32-bit size.

```
r = a * b
```

can be re-written as

```
r = (al + (ah << 16)) * (bl + (bh << 16))
```

where `al` and `ah` are the low and high 16-bit parts of `a`. Shifting by 16 is the same as multiplying by 2^16. We can then expand this equation.

```
r =  (al + (ah * 2^16)) * (bl + (bh * 2^16))
r =  al * bl + al * (bh * 2^16) + (ah * 2^16) * bl + (ah * 2^16) * (bh * 2^16)
r =  al * bl + al * bh * 2^16 + ah * bl * 2^16 + ah * bh * 2^32
r =  al * bl + (al * bh + ah * bl) << 16 + (ah * bh) << 2^32
```

So you end up with 4 multiplies (`al*bl`, `al*bh`, `ah*bl` & `ah*bh`) and you shift the results and add them together. Bear in mind that each 16-bit multiply produces a 32-bit result, so the whole thing will go into 64 bits. In your case, because you know `a` & `b` aren't bigger than 2^23 the whole thing will fit in 46 bits.

The other thing is that the summation will need to be done in 16-bit chunks, with the carry bits looked after.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this later to see if it works, but thank you for your response!

Comment: The result must be stored in the same format (that is, it must fit within 32 bits (2 16-bit words).  Basically I am multiplying two 23-bit mantissas together, but the upper 7 bits of the mantissa are in the upper 16-bit word, and the lower 16 bits are in another 16-bit word.

Comment: Mantissa?! Is this part of a floating point multiply? If that's the case the theory is the same, but you're interested in the MSB end. IEEE-748 has an implicit '1' bit on the MSB giving 24-bits. You then multiply them giving a 48-bit result, take the 24 MSBs, and then drop the MSB (which should be 1). As you're discarding the LSBs you can avoid doing the multiplies who's result lands up in the discarded region, in which case it's better to make `ah` & `bh` the 16 MSBs and `al` & `bl` the 8 lower bits. You can then drop the `al * bl` multiply, and the lower half of the `a/bl * b/ah` multiplies.

Comment: Thanks man!, but yes this is part of a floating point multiply. I think you mean IEEE-754 btw (not 748).

Comment: what do you mean by making `al` & `bl` the lower 8 bits? If we are avoiding the `al * bl` multiply, why would they be the lower 8 bits?

Comment: I was bumping up against the length limit. 24-bits into two sixteen bit words - You can either put the 16 LSBs into one and the 8 MSBs into the other, or you can put the 16 MSBs into one and the 8 LSBs into the other. As the mantissa is actually representing a fraction, it makes sense to do the second and zero pad the bottom end. For integer multiplication I'd do the first and zero pad the top end. It just puts the result in a better place.